# SWRL: How to use the built-in swrlb:booleanNot?

Tags: protege, swrl

I am using Protege 3.4.8. Say I have some instances with a datatype property `colors` and object property `hasMeaning`. The value of `colors` are represented by a string, e.g. `red blue yellow`.

I'd like to create a rule like this: If one's colors contain `red` but no `blue`, then it has the meaning `Happy`. My current rule is written as below:

`colors(?x, ?y)

∧ swrlb:contains(?y, "red")

∧  swrlb:booleanNot(true, swrlb:contains(?y,"blue"))

→  hasMeaning(?x, Happy)`

But I got `Error: Expecting ',' or ')', got '('.`

I followed the grammar provided [here](http://www.daml.org/rules/proposal/builtins.html#8.3).

Any idea of what's wrong here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Protégé 3.4.8 is really pretty old, and you'd be better off using the 4.x series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [abstract syntax for SWRL](http://www.daml.org/rules/proposal/abstract.html) has this grammar for atoms:

```
atom ::= description '(' i-object ')'
     | dataRange '(' d-object ')'
     | individualvaluedPropertyID '(' i-object i-object ')'
     | datavaluedPropertyID '(' i-object d-object ')' 
     | sameAs '(' i-object i-object ')' 
     | differentFrom '(' i-object i-object ')'
     | builtIn '(' builtinID { d-object } ')'
builtinID ::= URIreference
```

The syntax for a `builtIn` atom takes a list of `d-objects` as arguments.  The production for `d-object` is:

```
d-object ::= d-variable | dataLiteral
```

The atom `booleanNot( true, contains( ?string, "red" ))` is malformed because `contains( ?string, "red" )` is not a `d-object`, but an atom.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a way to get the desired behavior.  It would be very convenient if there was a `notContains` built-in…

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, I'm still seeking for a way to express what I want to achieve above. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @goldfrapp04 Unless SWRL has some additional built-ins (and I know that some reasoners provide an API for defining new ones) I'm not sure what you can do.  If you don't have to use SWRL rules, you could use SPARQL INSERT queries with WHERE clauses to get the same effects.  [SPIN](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2011/SUBM-spin-overview-20110222/) might be useful to consider if you take this route.